# if condition best practice

Tags: php

I have the following functions:

```
if(A==B)
{
  //do stuff
}

if(C==B)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

---

```
if(A==B)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
   else if(C==B)
   {
     //do stuff
}
```

What is the difference between these two? I get the meaning of it but I have seen programmers prefer the first one instead of the 2nd one? why?

I personally prefer the 2nd one.

Comment: word? hope u are joking?

Comment: ok! I get that? that has nothing to do with the question! for your kind info, I will change it

Comment: @C0dekid both are the same!!!

Comment: I am really sorry!!1

Comment: @C0dekid butter why you is sorry?

Comment: My statement was wrong, right? :p @TanvirAlam

Comment: The statements aren't logically the same at all, they work differently (e.g. if A is 5, B is 5 and C is 5), so you're trying to compare avocadoes with qinoa - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/p8b19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's mostly a question of preference. I saw many programmers using both cases regardless of the actual function.

But correctly use the first case if you want both conditions to be chekced absolutely, the second one as a nested condition.

In the first case, both will be executed which makes it slower than the second one, as it checks only for the `elseif`, if the `if` condition is false

---

```
$var = 1;

if($var+1 ==2)
{
  echo "test1";
}

if($var-0==1)
{
  echo "test2";
}


if($var+1==2)
{
    echo "test1";
}
else if($var-0==1)
{
    echo "test2";
}
```

will output

```
test1test2test1
```

so we see, that number 2 ignores the elseif, which makes it faster.

Comment: Both are the same: 2nd example: I am not break; or halting it anyway

Comment: does it have any influence on performance?

Comment: It's not the same. And not about preference. The code samples have different logic. @TechTreeDev Maybe you should have added an initial value for `$var` (e.g `$var = 1`) and some echos so you can actually run them and see the difference.

Comment: @AUsr19532: just check the edit :) your answer came 10 seconds after the commit

Comment: in you conditional statement, please note that the use of "yoda condition" can avoid you headache.

Normal condition:
if($myvar == 'string')

Yoda condition :
if('string' == $myvar)

The yoda condition permit you avoiding silent bug when you forget a =
if('string' = $myvar) --> will throw an error

if($myvar = 'string') --> can cause you headache

Comment: @erwan: Usually, I avoid it but for this it was not relevant for me. Feel free to edit, as I'm on my phone right now, which makes code editing quite uncomfortable-

Answer (score 0):

In the first condition both the statements are excecuted because they are independent to each other, so all of them will be tested.

```
if(A==B)
{
  //do stuff
}

if(C==B)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

In second else if is just a nested if inside an else, so only one will of them will be tested, either if or elseif

```
if(A==B)
{
  //do stuff
}
else if(C==B)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: If `A!=B` the code inside the if doesn't get executed, the test is performed though. Any statement gets test until one evaluates to true / all conditions failed

Answer (score 0):

Not the same.

else if (C==B) will not be executed (even if C equals B) if the first condition was true.

without "else", just if (C==B) will be executed even if the first condition was true (in that case A==C :)

Answer (score 0):

If only one variable is equal and need to run the same code regardless, it is better to use the first code so there is no loss of performance. But if you need to run different code depending on your variable, then the second is better.